# Unwanted Json result using mybatis result with hashmap

Tags: java, json, spring, hashmap, mybatis

my sqlmap.xml

```
<select id="getList" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT A,B,C,D FROM MYTABLE
</select>
```

result example

```
 A       B      C       D
john    123    math    100
jade    456    math     78
janet   789    math     98
```

controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/my/result.json")
public @ResponseBody List MyResult(){
    return myDAO.getList();
}
```

but, json result is looking confused column sort such as,

```
[
    {"B":123,"C":"math","A":"john","D":100},
    {"B":456,"C":"math","A":"jade","D":78},
    {"B":789,"C":"math","A":"janet","D":98}
]
```

I want get result with sql with defined Column names and index.
but in result, it's different column name index between sql and hashmap.
Any idea how to get json result same as sql result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue, in sqlmap, just set the `resultType` to `java.util.LinkedHashMap`:

```
<select id="getList" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
    SELECT A,B,C,D FROM MYTABLE
</select>
```